# find which yaml file was used for the any kubernetes resource?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

How to find, that which yaml file was used for the deployment of any kubernetes resource.

I checked "kubectl describe", it doesn't list the same, is there anyway to know.

use case:

I want to update the yaml and redeploy, one option, I guess is to generate the yaml from running resource, update and redeploy.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Try `kubectl edit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get yaml for your k8s application deployment.

Use [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources)

```
kubectl get deploy my-deployment -o yaml --export
 OR
kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml --export
 OR
kubectl get svc my-svc -o yaml --export
```

Editing is also simple.

```
kubectl get deploy my-deployment -o yaml --export > my-deployment.yml
<Edit the my-deployment.yml file and kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yml>

OR 

kubectl edit deployment my-deployment
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Flag --export has been deprecated, This flag is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Comment: Thanks, the export yml, option gives too many additional yml tags , addition to original yml, like   progressDeadlineSeconds: 600 and many annotations.

Second option : 
kubectl edit deployment my-deployment
looks much better, but i actually wanted to check, if there is a way to find exact yml file path, which was used during deployment ?
I guess, that may not be possible, because that would not be tracked by k8 as it may have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to get the content of an yaml file, that was used to create a deployment:
`kubectl apply view-last-applied <resource_type> <resource_name>`

In your case it will be similar to:
`kubectl apply view-last-applied deployment <deployment_name>`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can choose here from two options.

**Option 1:**

You can `grep` all YAMLs looking for specific annotations or labels.

```
$ grep "app: nginx-test" *.yaml
```

or

```
$ grep -e "prometheus.io/scheme: http" *.yaml
```

When you find proper file you can edit it (vi, nano, etc) and apply.

```
$ kubectl apply -f [yaml-name]
```

**Option 2:**

When you know name of your deployment you can edit it.

```
$ kubectl edit deployment [deployment-name]
```

You will see current deployment YAML with a `status:` section which describing current status of deployment. If you don't like vi, you can use nano instead

```
$ KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit [deployment-name]
```

If you want to create YAML from your current deployment I would advise you to use kubectl edit with `--export` flag. It will removes unneeded information (like `status:` from previous comment).

```
$ kubectl get deploy [your-deployment] -oyaml --export >> newDeployment.yaml
```

Hope it will help.